# How to plot a 2d function with PGFPLOTS usin $y$ as the independent variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create graphs of certain 2D functions using `pgfplots`. If the function is defined with `$x$` as the independent variable, there is no problem; however, if I try to plot a function with `$y$` as the independent variable, the following error appears:

```
    Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, you can't use 'y' in this context. PGFPlots expected      
    to sample a line, not a mesh. Please use the [mesh] option combined with [samples 
    y>0] and [domain y!=0:0] to indicate a twodimensional input domain.
```

I am not intending to plot a function with two dimensional domain (i.e., a 3D plot), but a regular 2D plot with `$x$` depending from `$y$`. A a matter of example, say I want to plot `$\sin{x}$` from `$-4\pi$` to `$4\pi$`. This code does the trick:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=-1,
legend cell align=left,
axis lines=middle,
enlargelimits=true,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xmin=-4,
xmax=4,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1.5]
        
\addplot[name path=A, smooth, color=lime, ultra thick, domain=-4*pi:4*pi, samples=100] {sin(deg(x))};
\addlegendentry{$y=\sin{x}$};
        
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: The result.]

So my question would be, how can I do the same for the function$\sin{y}$?

It should't be difficult, but I have found nothing in the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) (it's 570+ pages long!).

Comment: Are you searching for `\addplot ({sin(deg(x))},x);`?

Comment: Interchange the axis labels. If required, rotate the graph.

Comment: You can use any variable you want, but not `y` ( or `z`) . There is no reason to use `y` (or `z`) for anything else than the oridinate.